# Was this line from Show Dogs a cameo / pop culture reference?

Tags: analysis, reference, show-dogs

In *Show Dogs* (2018), there is a scene where they are outside a Las Vegas casino and two dogs are speaking in a seemingly random clip (as though they are being interviewed). One of the dogs says something like:

> "people just don't make talking dog movies anymore".

Since this film actually *is* a talking dog movie, this is clearly a kind of meta-joke at the very least.

At first, I thought the dog who said this was Rosebud from the "*Air Buddies*" movie series. The dog has a similar appearance. But I checked and Rosebud's most recent voice actress, *G Hannelius*, was not in the movie, at least not credited (according to IMDb). I also checked the two other voice actresses who have played Rosebud.

I'm not exactly an expert on talking dog movies so this could have been from some totally different movie I haven't seen.

Is this line a direct reference to some other movie, and if not, what's the point of this line?